# Devise: instead of creating a new user when signing up, convert an existing guest user into a registered one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, user-registration

When a guest comes to my website, he is automatically logged in as a `User.create guest: true`. This way he can easily write comments, etc., and doesn't have to decide to sign up at the very beginning.

If he likes to, he should be able then to sign up later. And here's my question: instead of signing up as a new user, I'd like to convert the existing guest user into a registered user.

Is there an easy way to tell devise to use an existing user? Another way would be to move all the created comments, etc. to the newly created user, but this seems a bit tedious. Or I could remove the guest user and change the newly created user's ID to the deleted one's. In both cases I have to be very careful about `dependent: :destroy` relations, so it seems rather a bad solution.

Any idea on how to convert the existing user is highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming [this is what you mean by guest user](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-a-guest-user) then that's just a regular User missing a few fields and with no validations run on it.

When creating a User from an existing guest user just:

```
def edit 
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update  
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  user.update_attributes(params[:user])
end
```

edit. 
You're literally just dealing with a CRUDy user update action. Have your `Sign Up` anchor tag direct to the edit page for that specific guest_user ala: `<%=link_to "Sign Up", edit_user_path(guest_user)%>`

I've updated the code example. Assuming you're using a scaffoldish setup, those methods should be in `users_controller`. You'll want some checks to make sure you handle missing params or errors.

I think you are tricking yourself into thinking you are dealing with a super special case. Guest User is just a User missing some information. Registration just means adding that information to the existing User instance.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. Yes I use the linked code from plataformatec, but where exactly should I hook into the sign up process and change the attributes?

Comment: I think I have to clarify this a bit: I don't want to change the usual sign up mechanisms, forms, etc., but simply want to convert an existing guest user into a registered user when submitting the "sign up" form. I have reformulated my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22428680/convert-an-existing-guest-user-to-a-registered-user