# Devise: Convert an existing guest user to a registered user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, registration

I'm logging every new user automatically into the site by creating a guest user as described here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user

This allows every user to use some basic stuff on my site, e.g. creating comments.

Now, when the user decides to register, I want to convert the guest user into a registered user.

I tried to implement my own `User.new_with_session` method like this:

```
def self.new_with_session(params, session)
  user = User.find(session[:guest_user_id])

  user.name                  = params[:name]
  user.email                 = params[:email]
  user.password              = params[:password]
  user.password_confirmation = params[:password_confirmation]
  user.created_at            = nil
  user.updated_at            = nil
  user.confirmed_at          = nil
  user.guest                 = false

  user
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  super
end
```

But this doesn't work. Somehow, when submitting the form, devise somehow seems to detect that the user already exists in the DB, and so doesn't even try to do validations on it, etc., but simply exits the sign up process (because it's thinking the user is already signed in) and forwards to some other page, which results in a "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing." flash message.

As far as I can tell, this happens somewhere **before** `Devise::RegistrationsController#create` is even called.

So here's my question: is there a way to tell Devise not to think a user is logged in **simply** because the user already exists in the DB (although I don't have an idea how Devise knows about the user after submitting the registration form)?

**Update**

I could track the problem down a bit further. Whenever `self.new_with_session` returns a persisted record, the registration process is cancelled, as described above. When returning a new object, the registration continues. But I can't figure out where this is checked upon...!?

Answer (score 2):

For the moment, I stick with the following solution.

Instead of trying to convert the guest user into a registered one during the registration process, I let Devise do its magic and then **after** the registration completes, using an `after` hook, I immediately remove the newly registered user, then I convert the guest user to a registered one, assign the attributes provided through the user form to the former guest and sign it in.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  after_filter :consolidate_registered_user_with_guest, only: :create,
                                                        if: -> { @user.valid? }

  def consolidate_registered_user_with_guest
    @current_user.annex_and_destroy!(@user)
    sign_in @current_user
  end
end
```

Then in `User.rb`:

```
def annex_and_destroy!(other)
  transaction do
    skip_confirmation_notification!

    other.delete
    other.attributes.except("id").each do |attribute, value|
      update_column attribute, value
    end

    self.save!
  end

  self
end
```

By using `update_column` I make sure that no before/after hooks are triggered, otherwise unpredictable things would happen, e.g. the confirmation mail would be re-sent (when setting the confirmation token), etc.

Keep in mind that any related records are **not** transferred from the created `@user` object to the existing `@current_user` automatically, so if you create any related objects (e.g. in an `after` hook), you have to manually move them, which is again a quite difficult thing. So I think it's best to avoid such a thing.

If anyone has a better solution, please tell me. Also I'm unsure whether this leaves some Devise stuff not tidied up in the background.

Answer (score 2):

I'm overriding the RegistrationsController create method like so:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    if user = User.find_by_email params[:user][:email]
      user.update_attributes params[:user]
      sign_in_and_redirect user, bypass: true
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

I'm just finding the user and updating them. Devise also has a helper that combines the `sign_in` method with a redirect.

If no user is found then carry on as normal.

Comment: This sounds very useful, thank you! I don't have the time to verify it myself at the moment, so I'll wait with checking the "answer" button.